# Java fixed-width file format read/write library

Tags: java, file, fixed-length-record

I'm looking for a good Java library that easily allows the read/write of fixed-width files. Needed for maintaining legacy systems, i.e. files are needed to work with COBOL.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482021/tactics-for-parsing-fixed-width-text-log-in-java

Comment: I ended up using BeanIO but thanks for help! Got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use ByteBuffer, possibly with memory mapped files.  This allows to read/write primitive type in big or little endian.  This option is best for fixed width binary data.

For fixed width text you can use `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `String.substring(from, to)` to get the fields you want. To output fixed width fields you can use `PrintWriter.printf(format, fields ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

[uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) parses/writes Fixed-Width inputs (as well as CSV and TSV). It has quite a lot of features you which could use.

Sample input:

```
YearMake_Model___________________________________Description_____________________________Price___
1997Ford_E350____________________________________ac, abs, moon___________________________3000.00_
1999ChevyVenture "Extended Edition"______________________________________________________4900.00_
1996Jeep_Grand Cherokee__________________________MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded_______4799.00_
1999ChevyVenture "Extended Edition, Very Large"__________________________________________5000.00_
_________Venture "Extended Edition"______________________________________________________4900.00_
```

Code to read:

```
FixedWidthFieldLengths lengths = new FixedWidthFieldLengths(4, 5, 40, 40, 8);
FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings(lengths);
//sets the character used for padding unwritten spaces in the file
settings.getFormat().setPadding('_');

// creates a fixed-width parser with the given settings
FixedWidthParser parser = new FixedWidthParser(settings);
// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(yourFile));
```

Output:

```
[Year, Make, Model, Description, Price]
[1997, Ford, E350, ac, abs, moon, 3000.00]
[1999, Chevy, Venture "Extended Edition", null, 4900.00]
[1996, Jeep, Grand Cherokee, MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded, 4799.00]
[1999, Chevy, Venture "Extended Edition, Very Large", null, 5000.00]
[null, null, Venture "Extended Edition", null, 4900.00]
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: That is a very good parser, but it doesn't allow you to go from the internal java structure to the fixed-width file, i.e. it is only a reader, not a writer.

Comment: @alianos It seems you didn't try the FixedWidthWriter. Check some examples here: https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/FixedWidthWriterExamples.java

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at Fixedformat4j: http://fixedformat4j.ancientprogramming.com/

It is the exact purpose of this library

Answer (score 1):

You could look at

- [JRecord](http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/)  Library to read/write cobol files from Java, supports a variety of Cobol Dialects and formats
- [cb2java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2java/)  Read Cobol files
- [Legstar](http://www.legsem.com/legstar/)  library to proces cobol ata
- [cb2xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/)   Converts Cobol files to Xml

Answer (score 1):

A schema based approach:

- [JSaPar](https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar) Allows you to specify a schema by which you can parse or generate fixed width text. Also does some basic type checking and type conversions.
- There is also a list of other libraries mentioned [here](https://org-tigris-jsapar.github.io/jsapar/links) that could be of help to you.