# How to read and sort data that's only separated by spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a data set that I wanted to read out and sort into arrays, the only problem is that all of the data is separated by spaces only.

I wanted to use loops to sort the data into a big multi-dimensional array, but since it's only separated by spaces I'm at a complete loss.

The data is sorted by a year followed by 6 spaces, then a month followed by three, then 31 sets of data for that month, each of which followed by 3 spaces. Like so:

```
1974      1   0.00   0.01
```

I'd wanted to do something like this:

```
while(year)
    //sort into annual array
        while(month)
            //sort into monthly array
                for(each individual data entry)
                    //sort each data entry into each month's array
```

Sorry if my wording isn't very good here. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Scanner` class?

Comment: String.split() would probably work as well.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best is to create a class for your data, then write a sort with a custom comparator.

You should use a `Scanner` to read in your data into your Data class, and store that in a List

```
public class MyData{
    Date date;
    float data[];
}
List<MyData> data = new ArrayList<MyData>();
/// add everything into data

Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<MyData>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyData data1, MyData data2) {
        // compare on year
    }
});
// Copy into new List

Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<MyData>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyData data1, MyData data2) {
        // compare on month
    }
});
/// keep sorting and copying
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Scanner` class is what you need here.

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourIntputStream);

Now write your loops that read your data using `scanner.nextInt()` or other methods provided by scanner. Check API doc for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "split"-method to transform the string into an array. E.g.:

```
String[] splittedString = yourString.split(      ) // six spaces
```

Then split every ArrayEntry again by 3 spaces and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the 4 fields you can could use

```
String sInput = "1974      1   0.00   0.01";
String[] fields = sInput.split("\\s+");
```

where `fields[0]` will be the year, `fields[1]` the month, and so on.

If you want to work on the sorted data, probably you'll need to pre-load all the fields in another array, in a struct for the data.

Comment: This is a *java* question, not a *.NET* question

Comment: I didn't notice. Adjusted the example.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Extract the data as an array by splitting on any number of whitespace:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
```

Step two extract the parts:

```
String year = words[0];
String month = words[1];
String [] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(words, 2, words.length);
```

This code caters for months with any number of days.

Answer (score 0):

I think your reading a fixed width file... can I suggest you look at fixedformat4j as mentioned in this answer [Tactics for parsing fixed-width text log in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482021/tactics-for-parsing-fixed-width-text-log-in-java)